# SQLite How do I match one column from multiple tables then return only one of those tables and add missing column only

Tags: sql, sqlite

SQLite How do I match one column from multiple tables then return only one of those tables.

I could do this if I run two queries and one of those queries will always return 0 rows other one will always return 1 vica-versa.

I have a table that has columns
`item, amount, price, sold, slot`
Another table that has columns
`item, amount, price, bought, slot`

I wanted to match both tables at once based on just the slot whichever has the slot I want.

Both tables cannot have the same slot in use at the same time anyways, 
But if some bug happens in the software where both tables use same slot, then it should output 2 rows should probably happen one row should have sold NULL other row should have bought NULL something like that.

Even if it works properly the output row should have both sold and bought just one of them being NULL so i can detect which kind of table it is.

This is what I got so far returns nothing

```
SELECT * FROM Buying B INNER JOIN Selling S USING(slot) WHERE B.slot = 0 OR S.slot = 0
```

Here is what I want after the SELECT

```
SELECT item, amount, price, bought, sold FROM Buying B INNER JOIN Selling S USING(slot) WHERE B.slot = 0 OR S.slot = 0
```

I know that using the USING command i'm doing (B.slot = S.slot) which obviously won't happen unless it bugs up, but I can't keep them joined by anything other then slot matches on either of them that's all I can do in my case.

The item, amount, price is different on both tables.. I would like to use the information from the table which has the slot match up if both match up then both answers should be outputted.

Comment: Why did you tag this mysql if it's only about sqlite?

Comment: I tagged it both to get answers from both since the question is general sql knowledge that works on both. It's like using HTML with XML in my book

Comment: The sql tag is for general SQL knowledge.

Comment: Okay I remove the mysql tag

Comment: Anyway, I gave an answer that will work in MySQL. I'm guessing it will also work in sqlite, I don't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a UNION:

```
SELECT item, amount, price, bought, NULL sold, slot
FROM Buying
WHERE slot = 0
UNION
SELECT item, amount, price, NULL bought, sold, slot
FROM Selling
WHERE slot = 0
```

Each subquery puts `NULL` in the column that comes from the other table.

Comment: Okay but how do I make a connection with both or either on slot = 0